# Problem Uninstalling Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-vista

On Windows Vista Home Premium (x64)

I am trying to uninstall Microsoft Internet Explorer. The procedures explained all over the web involve going through the control panel to Programs and Features. If MSIE is listed there, then uninstall in the usual way. If it is not listed there, click Turn Windows features on and off and deactivate it there. But Internet Explorer is not listed in either place.

Background: I initiated some process in MSIE a couple of months ago that caused all web pages to no longer save login information or remain logged in when requested. As you can tell from the way I described that, I don't remember what it was and have no way to simply reverse it. I had a few problems with .NET Framework as well. So, I've uninstalled all browsers except MSIE and uninstalled .NET Framework. I've reinstalled .NET Framework and all other browsers. I have not been able to uninstall MSIE.

Have Tried: I tried installing over the existing installation, but auto-update must be keeping it nicely up to date. The attempt simply produced an information window telling me that my current version is more up-to-date than the new version I tried to install.

Comment: Have you tried the show windows update button on the left of add/remove programs? This made IE9 show up in my list....

Comment: Just tried it. No effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't ever uninstall from windows. It is critical to the OS itself.

Running an uninstall process on IE will only effectively downgrade to the previous version installed, and if there is not a previous version, it should not be able to be uninstalled.

What is the reason behind your wanting to uninstall IE? Windows does allow other browsers to be default and so you can effectively ignore IE.

UPDATE: For updates in question "Background"
Many IE settings are user-specific. Try creating a new user account and see if the issues you're experiencing with IE occur in the new user account. This will help see if the issue is a global (ie, affecting the whole system, probably related to global settings and files), or just local to the user account.

Also, have you followed the steps here? http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=318378
Regardless of the patch level of your browser, you should still be able to repair install or reinstall the full app.

Comment: My understanding is that this WAS true, but after getting their arses pulverized by the EU, MS has been forced to provide a means of uninstalling IE. Granted, I've never personally tried. I just usually remove all desktop/start menu references to IE (or install Ubuntu).

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu. The EU ruling only really stipulated that they had to provide options. So in EU versions of Windows there is now a splash screen on first install where users are allowed to select from Chrome, Firefox, and Opera and then are taken to the appropriate sites for download and installation. Of course, the browser that gets them to those sites is IE. IE is an integral and critical part of explorer.exe, even in Windows 7.

Comment: Also the EU ruling does not force Microsoft to make changes for other regions. The asker may be in the US.

Comment: @KCotreau, yes that is true. However, I doubt MS employed such a significant structural difference between EU-version OSes and US-version OSes as having one rely so heavily on IE integration and one not. Any differences between the two would be limited, IMHO, to minor changes such as the browser selector app.

Comment: 1. I live in the EU. 2. My reason for wanting to uninstall MSIE is given in the original statement of the question. It's become screwed up. I've tried to find a way to solve the problems it has. I'm down to the last resort - uninstall / re-install in an effort to correct it.

Comment: Regarding auto-update. Windows Update will only run as you have configured it to. I recommend setting Windows Update to Prompt so that it'll ask you before installing further updates. This may allow you to get "behind" on a couple updates and then force-install them yourself.

Comment: There is NO difference of EU and US versions of Windows, except for the "N" versions, that do not contain Windows Media. All tricks to uninstall IE work by just hiding it and maybe deleting a few uncritical files.

Comment: @bot47, which is why we're discussing how to perform reinstalls, repair installs, and the like.

Comment: I've tried resetting to original settings as suggested @  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=318378 (given in the answer above). That seems to have partially corrected the problems I've been having. MSIE still isn't working well enough to use as a default browser (still can't remain logged in to my home page between boot-ups); but I can survive that for now with another browser as my default. I suppose it's maybe just commentary to add that it's not nice to lose control of one's computer but that's been going on with MS for quite a few years.

Comment: Can you check your temporary internet directory and possibly find the cookie your homepage sets? Then see if that cookie still exists after a reboot. If it has been deleted after a reboot, your system may be deleting temp files during reboot.

Comment: If it's doing that, what would correct it?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure off-hand of any default windows processes that do such things, but I'm sure they're out there. Check the scheduled tasks or start up entries. If you're on a domain, check your startup and shutdown scripts.